# Location problems about Citymaps

Tags: android, citymaps

I had meet some location problems about CityMaps that as follows：

1、I have create an Activity which extends FragmentActivity implements interface MapViewReadyListener, LocationSource, LocationListener，and then inital the SupportCitymapsMapFragment instance，set some parameters as follows:

```
    fragment = (SupportCitymapsMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    mParams = new LocationParams(1, 1000, 1000);


    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.getMapView().startUpdatingLocation();
        fragment.getMapView().getBusinessLayer().setVisible(false);
        fragment.getMapView().getRegionLayer().setVisible(false);
        fragment.setMapViewReadyListener(MainActivity.this);
        fragment.getMapView().setLocationSource(this);
    }
```

in the method onLocationChanged(Location location)，I set the map position like this：

```
    CitymapsMapView map = fragment.getMapView();
    map.getBusinessLayer().setVisible(false);
    map.getRegionLayer().setVisible(false);
    LonLat position = new LonLat(location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
    int zoom = 15;
    float orientation = 45.0f;
    float tilt = 15.0f;
    MapPosition mapPosition = new MapPosition(position, zoom, orientation, tilt);
    map.setMapPosition(mapPosition);
```

But when I open gps and my app，I found postion that display on the map is not my current position but the last place，more importantly，the map does not loading out sometimes even my network is very well，Why？

2、I am try to get the longitude/latitude coordinate with other way，and I create the MapView with a traditional way。When I go to a new place and open my app，I found the arrow still at the last place but the toast had give me tips about my current position correctly。After about half an hour，open the app again，it is just right，Why is it so？

3、I have add label to a marker，whether i can customized the font style of the label？

Answer (score 0):

I am a developer on the Citymaps SDK, I will do my best to answer your questions.

1) It seems you are misunderstanding how the `LocationSource` interface works.  Please look at [CitymapsLocationSource.java](https://bitbucket.org/citymaps/citymaps-android-map-library/src/5a8bafc9638a99c122ba671683299185f9796a48/src/com/citymaps/citymapsengine/CitymapsLocationSource.java?at=master) to see a sample implementation.

2) If you are using a custom location source, it is up to you to let the map know when the location has changed

3) At this time, that API is not exposed.  If you wish to have a marker label with custom fonts, I suggest rendering a custom `ViewGroup` to a `Bitmap` and setting that `Bitmap` as the marker's image.